# C++, возможно ли разрезолвить одну функцию внутри другой, локально

Tags: c++, c

В `*.cpp` файле есть множество `static` функций. Я бы не хотел загрязнять код лишними предварительными объявлениями. Практически все функции вызывают лишь те функции, которые определены ранее. Но есть несколько особенных функций, для которых приходится использовать предварительное объявление того, с чем они работают.

Я предположил, что могу сделать это предварительное объявление в теле необходимой функции, локально. Но видимо из-за того, что все функции являются внутренними (`static`), линкер начинает ругаться.

Например:

```
static void f1(const float _f1)
{
    void f2(const float _f2);
    f2(_f1 + 1);// Error
}

static void f2(const float _f2)
{
}

int main()
{
    f1(1);
    return 0;
}
```

На что линкер сообщает:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol 'void f1(...)...'
```

Важное уточнение: код компилирую компилятором `C++`. Если же попытаться собрать код `C` компилятором, то ошибки будут на этапе компиляции, а не линковки.

Comment: А что такое `1.f` в аргументе функции?

Comment: @freim, просто параметр.

Comment: Что он должен обозначать? Число какое-то?

Comment: @freim, эот не имеет значения. Это просто параметр, в данном случае = 1.000000f.

Comment: У вас f оттуда похоже в неопределенные символы попадает, не могу только сообразить как. Попробуйте написать просто 1.0

Comment: @freim, дело не в этом. Можно вообще убрать из функции параметры. Они здесь просто для примера.

Comment: Так. А что это за объявление функции внутри функции? С++ это не Паскаль, вложенных функций в нем нет. Понял, это я просмотрел. Вы решили попробовать новый продвинутый синтаксис. Ну-ну. :)

Comment: Я просто очень долгое время писал на нескольких языках и, видимо, решил, что предварительные объявления функций можно пихать внутрь функций... Получается, так делать нельзя? Путаницы вносит еще и то, что `GNU GCC C` в принципе позволяет объявлять и определять вложенные функции.

Comment: @freim: Что за чушь??? Никто здесь не пытается *определять* функции внутри других функций. Речь идет об обычных *объявлениях*, которые существуют в С и С++ со времен динозавров. Это классика языка. Какой еще "новый продвинутый синтаксис"? (И кто плюсует таки комментарии?)

Comment: @MGNeo: Можно, и всегда было можно. Только последствия такого объявления - не такие, как вы ожидаете.

Comment: @freim, **nested function** вроде никто не отменял https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_function - `С++ это не Паскаль, вложенных функций в нем нет`

Comment: @NewView: Вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к вложенным функциям. Автор вопроса не пытается сделать ничего подобного. Вопрос совершенно о другом.

Comment: @AnT, я собственно среагировал на утверждение: `С++ это не .., вложенных функций в нем нет` , что вижу о том и пою.. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Внутри функций можно объявлять только функции с `extern` линковкой. Функции со `static` линковкой необходимо объявлять непосредственно в единице трансляции.

```
static void f2(const float _f2);

static void f1(const float _f1)
{
    f2(_f1 + 1);
}

static void f2(const float _f2)
{
}

int main()
{
    f1(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Как альтернатива, чтобы не писать везде `static`, можно обернуть эти функции в анонимное пространство имен:

```
namespace
{
    void f2(const float _f2);

    void f1(const float _f1)
    {
        f2(_f1 + 1);
    }

    void f2(const float _f2)
    {
    }    
}
```